# HX from Building library getting errors but simulating

Tags: modelica, dymola

I used heat exchanger from Building library and changed the media to MSL media. I am getting the warning as mentioned in the figure. But, It is simulating. Can anyone tell me what the warning represents? How to avoid it [image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

The warning seems to indicate that you have a variable where the nominal-attribute cannot be evaluated to a literal.

A trivial model would be:

```
model M
  Real x(nominal=p);
  parameter Real p=10 annotation(Evaluate=false);
equation 
  der(x)=1-x;
end M;
```

The warning indicates that since the attribute couldn't be evaluated it is ignored, as if it hadn't been set.

The nominal-attribute is used for scaling of variables (in particular states), and should indicate the natural scale of the variable - and it is most important if the variable varies on scale substantially different from 1 and may be close to zero; so it seems somewhat important in this case.

The answer by @ReneJustNielsen indicates the likely cause.

Comment: Will this effect my simulation?

Comment: A missing (or bad) nominal value can make the simulation slower or less accurate. But you can avoid the inaccurate result by using a tighter tolerance in the simulation setup.

Answer (score 1):

It looks as if you have a component `volume` in your model to which you haven't assigned a medium model (air) but only kept the default `PartialMedium`

Comment: I will change it sir. What about the warning that is saying non- literal value. What is that error?